# regex for pos tagged text for extract location

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

i am using stanford pos tagger for tagging tweet content. i need to extract locations like "the golden gate bridge" or "tiburon blvd", etc. i have some rules for detecting location, that are:

```
1.<NN>+ 
2.<DT>?<JJ>?<1> ----> <1>:it means the rule number 1
3.<CD>?<2>
4.<2> <CD>?
5.(3|4) <CC | PE> (3|4)
```

The “+” sign indicates the presence of a tag at least one or
more times, the “?” sign indicates the presence of a tag zero or
one time, and the “|” sign indicates the presence of one of the
two tags. 
and we have Nouns (NN), Determiners
(DT), Adjectives (JJ), Cardinal Numbers (CD), Conjunctions
(CC), and Possessive Endings (PE) from pos tagger.

A sample pos tagged sentence: "this/DT overturned/VBN tanker/NN in/IN marin/NN has/VBZ created/VBN a/DT huge/JJ jam/NN on/IN wb/NN 580/CD clear/JJ across/IN the/DT richmond/JJ san/NN rafael/NN bridge/NN &/CC Four/CD"

can any one help me with creating regex for each rule in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there probably are better / more efficient solutions, this should work:

```
1. (\w+/NN)(\s(\w+/NN))*
2. (\w+/DT\s)?(\w+/JJ\s)?(\w+/NN)(\s(\w+/NN))*
3. (\w+/CD\s)?(\w+/DT\s)?(\w+/JJ\s)?(\w+/NN)(\s(\w+/NN))*
4. (\w+/DT\s)?(\w+/JJ\s)?(\w+/NN)(\s(\w+/NN))*(\s\w+/CD)?
5. ((<3>)|(<4>))\s((\w+/CC)|(\w+/PE))\s((<3>)|(<4>))
```

A little explanation:
`(\w+/NN)` extracts any combination of characters (at least one) followed by a forward slash and "NN" (e.g. tanker/NN). If we combine that with a whitespace (\s), we can extract any arbitrary number of consecutive nouns.

For the second rule we add two optional parts which extract ".../DT" and ".../JJ" and combine it with rule one. Rule three just adds another optional part which extracts ".../CD" and combine it with rule two. For rule four, we append an optional ".../CD" to rule two.

For the fifth rule you have to replace `<3>` and `<4>` with the respective rule. Otherwise it would look a bit complex. The middle part extracts ".../CC" or ".../PE" and we append and prepend a pattern to match either rule three or rule four.